# Integrating Yahoo Sports API Data

Tags: r, yql, yahoo-api

I have been following the code from [here](https://rpubs.com/kuhnrl30/ConnectToYahooAPIUsingR), which works until the "yahoo_token" step that yields the following:

```
 yahoo_token<- oauth2.0_token(yahoo, myapp, cache=T, use_oob = T)
     Please point your browser to the following url: 

     https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?client_id=dj0yJmk9Uk1waEVUSWNhQmF1JmQ9WVdrOVpXNUNTelZDTnpZbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD04OA--&scope=&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code

     Enter authorization code:
```

I then have no idea what the authorization code is. The link they ask me to point my browser to also asks for a code but none was provided to me at any point during this process.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after changing my request for authorization to:

```
yahoo_token<- oauth1.0_token(yahoo, myapp, cache=T)
```

Comment: This worked for me previously but now I am having sign-in issues with Yahoo. I tried using `oauth2.0_token` but I also don't know what the authorization code when prompted. Can anyone help clarify?